# LinkedIn EasyApply API (/v2/jobApplications) returns HTTP 500, serviceErrorCode:2003. What does it mean?

Tags: linkedin-api

Requests like the one below:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/jobApplications?q=jobPostings&jobPostings=urn:li:jobPosting:1111111111&jobPostings=urn:li:jobPosting:2222222222&projection=(elements*(member~(firstName,lastName),contactEmail,contactPhoneNumber,jobPosting,id,applyDate,resume),paging)&appliedUntilDate=1597691706&appliedAfterDate=1596482106
```

return the following all the time:

```
Message: {"message":"Internal Server Error","serviceErrorCode":2003,"status":500}
HResult: -2146233079
```

Can anyone please let me know

1. What serviceErrorCode:2003 means?
2. Is there any API reference with the list of serviceErrorCode codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`serviceErrorCode:2003` simply means that job posting with the provided id was not found.